# Convert JQuery function w/each to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I need some help. I am using a multilingual static site w/JQuery and JSON but I would like to use it w/simple JS. Most part of the code is finished but I cannot resolve the commented part of the JS successfully (w/JQuery it is working well).

```js
var language, translate, jsData;

// Here is the questioned part in JQuery
translate = function(jsdata) {
  $('[block]').each(function(index) {
    var strTr;
    strTr = jsdata[$(this).attr('block')][$(this).attr('txt')];
    $(this).html(strTr);
  });
};


document.querySelector("a#hu").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // getJson('hu');
  jsData = {
    "1.md": {
      "title": "teszt 1",
      "body": "Szia Világ!"
    },
    "2.md": {
      "title": "teszt 2",
      "body": "Szia Világ megint!"
    }
  }
  translate()

});


document.querySelector("a#en").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // getJson('hu');
  jsData = {
    "1.md": {
      "title": "test 1",
      "body": "Hello Word!"
    },
    "2.md": {
      "title": "test 2",
      "body": "Hello Word again!"
    }
  }
  translate()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a hrf="#" id="hu">HU</a>
<a hrf="#" id="en">EN</a>
<p block="1.md" txt="title"></p>
<p block="1.md" txt="body"></p>
```

Comment: Please post what attempts you have made.

Comment: Also note that `block` and `txt` are not standard attributes in any HTML element. I'd suggest using `data` attributes instead, if you want to add custom metadata to the DOM

Comment: Agree with above, but would go further and just stick to an ID(if only 1 element)/class(multiple elements) and use the document.getElementBy, then just use the standard forEach ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Which kind of "problem" are you facing?

Comment: I updated your code in a snippet. Your AJAX likely works. Please make the snippet run

Comment: You are expecting jsData in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the comments.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("[block]")]
   .forEach(block => block.innerHTML = jsData[block.getAttribute("block")][block.getAttribute("txt")]);
```

```js
let language, jsData;

// Here is the questioned part in JQuery
const translate = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-block]")].forEach(
    block =>
    block.innerHTML = jsData[block.getAttribute("data-block")][block.getAttribute("data-txt")]
  );
};


document.querySelector("a#hu").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // getJson('hu');
  jsData = {
    "1.md": {
      "title": "teszt 1",
      "body": "Szia Világ!"
    },
    "2.md": {
      "title": "teszt 2",
      "body": "Szia Világ megint!"
    }
  }
  translate()

});


document.querySelector("a#en").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // getJson('hu');
  jsData = {
    "1.md": {
      "title": "test 1",
      "body": "Hello Word!"
    },
    "2.md": {
      "title": "test 2",
      "body": "Hello Word again!"
    }
  }
  translate()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a hrf="#" id="hu">HU</a>
<a hrf="#" id="en">EN</a>
<p data-block="1.md" data-txt="title"></p>
<p data-block="1.md" data-txt="body"></p>
<p data-block="2.md" data-txt="title"></p>
<p data-block="2.md" data-txt="body"></p>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I refreshed my question.

Comment: Thank you for your help!